# Most efficient way to get the substring after a specific other substring

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, substring

If I have a string that looks something like this:

```
String text = "id=2009,name=Susie,city=Berlin,phone=0723178,birthday=1991-12-07";
```

I only want to have the info `name` and `phone`. I know how to parse the entire String, but in my specific case it is important to only get those two "fields".

So what is the best/most efficient way to have my search method do the following:

**search for the substring "name=" and return the substring after it ("Susie") until it reaches the next comma**

My approach would have been to:

1. get the last index of "name=" first
2. use this index then as the new start for my parsing method

Any other suggestions maybe on how this could be done more efficiently and with a more condense code? Thank you for any input

Comment: Use `split`. And if you really have a performance problem, benchmark.

Comment: Use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to capture only what comes after `name=` and `phone=`

Comment: split by `,`, split by `=`, loop over the first array and check if the item for the second split at index `0` is equal to what you are searching and return the next splittet array and what is one the current index in your loop at index `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use following regex to capture the expected word after `phone` and `name` and get frist group from matched object:

```
(?:phone|name)=([^,]+)
```

With regards to following command if it might happen to have a word which is contain `phone` or `name` as a more comprehensive way you can putt a comma before your name.

```
(?:^|,)(?:phone|name)=([^,]+)
```

Read more about regular expression http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: One corner case that will cause this regex to break is when there are fields that end in "name" or "phone" like "user_name" and "cell_phone".

Comment: Ok, can someone tell  me how I would use this regex in a code? (Sorry, I know the basics, but this looks a little too advanced...)

Comment: @mattforsythe Yep, checkout the edit.And thanks for attention.

Comment: Now you have another corner case: it won't work when "phone" or "name" are the first pair in the string.  :)  I think what you want is `(?:^|,)(?:phone|name)=([^,]+)`

Comment: @lilisyn Due to this point that you didn't provided any code and SO is not a code writing service I just gave this answer as a hint, you can search about the proper java function or approach to find all the cases that match whit this patter.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Regex might be more efficient, but for readability, I <3 [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

```
    String text = "id=2009,name=Susie,city=Berlin,phone=0723178,birthday=1991-12-07";

    final Map<String, String> infoMap = Splitter.on(",")
            .omitEmptyStrings()
            .trimResults()
            .withKeyValueSeparator("=")
            .split(text);

    System.out.println(infoMap.get("name"));
    System.out.println(infoMap.get("birthday"));
```